# Where can I find WP_CONTENT_DIR in Wordpress structure?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am using Query Monitor plugin, but it didn't create db.php symlink in path/to/wordpress/wp-content/db.php, even if I changed permission of the wp-content folder. My changing permission is restricted to one folder or file each time. 
I can't do Linux nor Windows command-line queries. There is only one db.php inside query-monitor folder.

This is a quote from Query Monitor plugin:

> When Query Monitor is unable to symlink its db.php file into place
>
> Occasionally PHP won't have the correct permissions to put this
>   symlink in place. Query Monitor will still work fine in this
>   situation, but you won't see extended information that makes Query
>   Monitor much more useful.
>
> You can manually create the symlink by running the following command
>   on the command line:
>
> Linux / OS X:
>
> ln -s
>   /path/to/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/query-monitor/wp-content/db.php
>   /path/to/wordpress/wp-content/db.php
>
> Windows (requires administrator privileges):
>
> mklink C:\path\to\wordpress\wp-content\db.php
>   C:\path\to\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\query-monitor\wp-content\db.php
>
> **> Alternatively, you can relax the file permissions on the
>   WP_CONTENT_DIR directory and then de-activate and re-activate the
>   plugin and it'll attempt to create the symlink again.**

Changing query-monitor or wp-content folder to 777 and de-activate + re-activate plugin has no effect. I don't think I can change permissions in phpMyAdmin, but no idea if I can or not on a table, and no idea how to find and change permissions on that table neither.

Is WP_CONTENT_DIR a php file or line in a file or a table or something else and where is it?

In case it's a line in a php file, how can I change permissions on a php line ?

Answer (score 1):

After many tries, I found out. One thing important: needs a path that begins with /home and can't be done offline else you'll get a conflict because it points to your computer.

No need to download nothing.

Cpanel may have Cron Jobs, which allows one linux bash shell command line as seen in [this article](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9561/29/how-to-create-a-symbolic-link-in-cpanel) (they don't host me). SSH client can also do this but it's more complicated.

Go to *Advanced* then *Cron Jobs* then set *Once per minute*:

```
ln -s /home/YOUR_HOST_USER_OR_ID/public_html/YOUR_BLOG_FOLDER/wp-content/plugins/query-monitor/wp-content/db.php /home/YOUR_HOST_USER_OR_ID/public_html/YOUR_BLOG_FOLDER/wp-content/db.php
```

Refresh till file is created, then delete Cron Job immediately after, to avoid repetition x2 on the 2nd minute.

So like that you avoid both errors:

Extended query information such as the component and affected rows is not available. Query Monitor was unable to symlink its db.php file into place. See this wiki page for more information.

Extended query information such as the component and affected rows is not available. A conflicting db.php file is present. See this wiki page for more information.